# Differences between types of exponential functions?

Tags: functions, exponential-function, graphing-functions

Can someone point out the key differences between functions of the form $ax^n$ and $ab^x$?

I'm only able to see certain differences when I plot examples for both, for example, it looks like $ax^n$ will either be an even function or a function with the domain as $\mathbb{R}$.

More?

Comment: $ax^n$ is called a "polynomial" (or sometimes "monomial" in this special case). There are plenty of differences, not sure what you are asking for. I would suggest you have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key difference that it should be pointed out is that

> $ax^n$ **is not** an exponential function, it's a polynomial. While $ab^x$ **is** indeed an exponential function.

We call a function exponential when the *indipendent variable* appears as the *exponent* of some number. We instead call *polynomial* every function consisting of variables and coefficients, that involves only the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and non-negative integer exponents of variables (cfr. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial#Polynomial_functions)).

We know lots of properties about this two type of function. As an example here's a simple list

1. *Exponentials* are either **increasing** ($b>1$) or **decreasing** ($0<b<1$) or **constant** ($b=1$) $\forall x \in \mathbb R$
   On the other hand, *polynomials* are not. They can increase or decrease constantly in some intervals (e.g. the *parabola* $y=x^2$ is decreasing for $x\in(-\infty, 0]$ and increasing for $x\in[0, \infty)$)
2. *Exponentials* are **always** positive or negative, depending on the constant $a$: $ab^x\gt 0$ $\forall x\in\mathbb R$ if $a>0$, if $a<0$ then $ab^x\lt0$ $\forall x$. On the other hand *polynomials* are not always one ore another.

And there are many more properties, more than I could write down in hours. For completeness see the relative pages on wikipedia:  [*exponential funcion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function), [*polynomials*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial).